# django heroku server error

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis

i have a django project which was uploaded to heroku. In my django project I used redis also to store some data. the application works on heroku but It happens that when ever I click a link, I get the error `Server Error (500)` I do not know the cause of the error but here is my redis setting that I use on local and development server.

`#REDIS FOR VIEWS
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DB = 3`

further codes would be provided on request

Answer (score 0):

Well, Redis isn't going to be running on localhost on Heroku.

You don't say how you have set up Redis, but presumably you are using one of the add-ons available through Heroku. These usually expose their configuration through an environment variable, which you would then use in your settings.py exactly as you do for the database settings. The add-on documentation itself will tell you what variable to use.

Comment: Yes i used ` heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev` how do I configure the setting in my development settings because the error is giving me a headache

Comment: As [the heroku-redis docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis) show, you need to use `os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')`.

Comment: so I just have to replace the entire view above with `os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')`

Comment: `r=redis.StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_HOST,port=settings.REDIS_PORT, db=settings.REDIS_DB)` how do I change this in my views.py